# Performing Load/Stress Testing on Flutter Application

Tags: android, ios, flutter, testing, mobile

My team and I have a Flutter application published to the Google Play & App Store, and are planning to launch it at a conference that is a month away.

We're looking to perform load testing on the app - basically the goal being to see if our frontend & backend can handle many users on the application at once, with those users interacting with different features at once.

We've tried searching up some options but ultimately led nowhere; none of them seem to be tailored towards a Flutter app. Looking for any ideas/knowledge or other recommendations on how we should do load/stress testing. For reference, we expect around 3000 users at the conference. We could get 200-300 users on the application from people we know - but not sure if that will be scalable to 3000.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the clients cannot talk directly to each other, each client would have to connect to the server. In that case, performance testing of the app only plays a minor role (only UI render times). I would focus on testing the backend through your API with a mock client, which you can then scale to test it with different loads and size your deployment according to your measurements (response times, simultaneous connections, etc.). It is important that the mock clients send requests in a similar pattern to a real user to get meaning full results.

PS: Keep in mind that depending on the location of the conference, the network could be a bottleneck as well.